# Share pdf with a friend via email

Tags: email

I'm trying to allow the site visitor to send a PDF to a friend via a button click from the Wordpress page. The problem is that the PDF should be automatically uploaded (which is a different PDF for each page). Is there a quick and easy way to do that? Thank you